# Вывести данные из бд, таблицы

Tags: javascript, php

Есть таблица, нужно при нажатии чтобы выводилась подробная информация. Но при нажатии я когда я нажимаю появляется данные только 1 строки таблицы.

```php
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Функция показа
    function show(state, id){
      if(id)
      { 
        boxid = id; 
        document.getElementById('window'+ id).style.display = state;            
        document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = state; 
      }
      else
      {
        document.getElementById('window'+ boxid).style.display = state;
        document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = state;
      }
    }


</script>
<?

?>
    
        <?
    }
    $tim=date("H",time()); 
    if($tim>16)
    {
        $temp = mktime(0,0,0)+24*60*60;
    }
    else
    {
        $temp = mktime(0,0,0);
    };
    $class = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `orders`");
//  $ress = mysqli_query($CONNECT,"SELECT * FROM `homework` WHERE `timestamp`> $temp ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($class))
    {

            ?>

            <div id="window2" class="boxstyle">
            <span class="close" onclick="show('none')">X</span>
            <form action="ordergo" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Название" name="name" value="<?= $row['name'] ?>"  disabled></p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Оплата" name="pay" value="<?= $row['pay'] ?>"  disabled></p>
            <textarea id="task" class="task"  placeholder="Описание" name="task"  disabled><? echo  $row['task']; ?> </textarea></p>

            <input type="text" placeholder="Сроки" name="name" value="<?=gmdate("d-m-Y", $row['timestamp'])?>"  disabled></p>
            <p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Выполняет" value="<?= $row['booster'] ?>" name="goo" disabled></p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Прогресс" value="<?= $row['progress'] ?>" name="progress" disabled></p>
            <p align="center"><button name="submit">Выполнить</button></p>
            </form>
        </div>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="show('block', '2')"><a href="#"><?= $row['name'] ?></a></td>
                <td><?= $row['pay'] ?></td>
                <td><?=gmdate("d-m-Y", $row['timestamp'])?></td>
                <td><?= $row['status']?></td>
                <td><form action='sdorderform' method='POST'></p>
                    <input type = 'text' name = 'id' value ='<?= $row['id'] ?>' hidden>
                    <button name='submit'>Удалить</button>
                </form>
            </td>

        </tr>

            <?
    }
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задам глупый вопрос, а в таблице точно больше одной строки есть с данными?

Comment: Да больше одной строки

Comment: Добавил скриншоты, на какое бы я название не нажал всё равно открывается диалоговое окно с данными 1 строки

Comment: Так вам нужны не вообще все данные из таблицы, а только по выбранной вами строке? Тогда в запросе нужно поставить условие. Что-то вроде того: SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE name = 'название'
а само название брать как параметр из нажатой ссылки. Иначе цикл будет содержать все строки таблицы и начинаться всегда с первой.

Comment: @Quazimorda, причем здесь sql запрос - если JS скрипт и генерация html составлено коряво?

Comment: @skypwnz, вот вам вопрос который должен натолкнуть на ответ - в JS вы проверяете какой то ID - но в цикле я не вижу этот ID. По какому атрибуту показывается или скрывается информация?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, если человеку нужно показать данные по конкретной выбранной строчке, то эту строчку в запросе надо как-то обособить, а остальные ошибки я в расчёт не брал.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, А  можно код как будет правильно? До сих пор ещё не сделал

Comment: Как правило это означает что идентификаторы одинаковые. Посмотрите код сгенерированной страницы

Comment: td onclick="show('block', '2')" - двойка так и должна быть константой?

Comment: id="window2" у вас в цигле генерруються элементы с одинаковым айди. Могу припустить что вместо 2 там должно быть айди записи

Comment: Сделал, благодарю

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Данные из таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1173064/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что участник уже задавал этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил id события `window<?= $row['id'] ?>` и `onclick="show('block', '<?= $row['id'] ?>')"`

```
   <?
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($class))
        {
                ?>
                <div id="window<?= $row['id'] ?>" class="boxstyle">
                <span class="close" onclick="show('none')">X</span>
                <form action="ordergo" method="POST">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Название" name="name" value="<?= $row['name'] ?>"  disabled></p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Оплата" name="pay" value="<?= $row['pay'] ?>"  disabled></p>
                <textarea id="task" class="task"  placeholder="Описание" name="task"  disabled><? echo  $row['task']; ?> </textarea></p>
    
                <input type="text" placeholder="Сроки" name="name" value="<?=gmdate("d-m-Y", $row['timestamp'])?>"  disabled></p>
                <p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Выполняет" value="<?= $row['booster'] ?>" name="goo" disabled></p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Прогресс" value="<?= $row['progress'] ?>" name="progress" disabled></p>
                <p align="center"><button name="submit">Выполнить</button></p>
                </form>
            </div>
                <tr>
                
                    <td onclick="show('block', '<?= $row['id'] ?>')" ><a href="#"><?= $row['name'] ?></a></td>
                    <td><?= $row['pay'] ?></td>
                    <td><?=gmdate("d-m-Y", $row['timestamp'])?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['status']?></td>
                    <td>
                    <form action='sdorderform' method='POST'></p>
                        <input type = 'text' name = 'id' value ='<?= $row['id'] ?>' hidden>
                        <button name='submit'>Удалить</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
    
                <?
        }
    ?>
    <?bottom()?>
```

Comment: @u_mulder, отредактировал

Comment: Можете не благодарить :D