# Данные из таблицы

Tags: javascript, php

нужно чтобы при нажатии на каждое название появлялось окно с подробной информацией. Но работает только с 1 строкой таблицы, если на другие названия нажимаю всё равно открывается 1. Подскажите как это сделать

```
         function show(state, id){
  if(id)
  { 
    boxid = id; 
    document.getElementById('window'+ id).style.display = state;            
    document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = state; 
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('window'+ boxid).style.display = state;
    document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = state;
  }
}
    </script>

    <?
}
$tim=date("H",time()); 
if($tim>16)
{
    $temp = mktime(0,0,0)+24*60*60;
}
else
{
    $temp = mktime(0,0,0);
};
$class = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `orders`");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($class))
{
        ?>
                    <div id="window2" class="boxstyle">
        <span class="close" onclick="show('none')">X</span>
        <form action="ordergo" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Название" name="name" value="<?= $row['name'] ?>"  disabled></p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Оплата" name="pay" value="<?= $row['pay'] ?>"  disabled></p>
        <textarea id="task" class="task"  placeholder="Описание" name="task"  disabled><? echo  $row['task']; ?> </textarea></p>

        <input type="text" placeholder="Сроки" name="name" value="<?=gmdate("d-m-Y", $row['timestamp'])?>"  disabled></p>
        <p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Выполняет" value="<?= $row['booster'] ?>" name="goo" disabled></p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Прогресс" value="<?= $row['progress'] ?>" name="progress" disabled></p>
        <p align="center"><button name="submit">Выполнить</button></p>
        </form>
    </div>
        <tr>
        
            <td onclick="show('block', '2')" ><a href="#"><?= $row['name'] ?></a></td>
            <td><?= $row['pay'] ?></td>
            <td><?=gmdate("d-m-Y", $row['timestamp'])?></td>
            <td><?= $row['status']?></td>
            <td>
            <form action='sdorderform' method='POST'></p>
                <input type = 'text' name = 'id' value ='<?= $row['id'] ?>' hidden>
                <button name='submit'>Удалить</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>

        <?
}
```

?>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]